# Can't display new html page with href from homepage

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7, django-views

The only examples I find. are related to issues with login page and iteration to other pages but not in the way I have the problem, so here is the issue I have to deal with -

I want to display a form for creating an account with multiple steps, using modals, when a user access the button "subscribe"

on my homepage.html I have this:

```
<a onClick="window.location.href='account'" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" value="account">
</a> `
```

...which is supposed to go to a new account.html page, in the same folder as my homepage.html

in my app's urls.py, where the apps' name is homepage I have:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from homepage import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    url(r'^account$', views.account, name='account'),   

)
```

and in my views I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from homepage.models import Email

def tmp(request):
    latest_email_list = Email.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:0]
    context = {'latest_email_list': latest_email_list}
    return render(request, 'home_page/homepage.html', context)

def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'home_page/homepage.html')

def account(request):
    return render(request, 'home_page/account.html')`
```

when I click on the button I get

Not Found

The requested URL /account was not found on this server.

I am a complete beginner in django and python so I really haven't yet wrapped my mind on how to work properly with the urls, views, and models together but I assume I have something wrongly defined in my views

would be grate if someone could help me setting this up,
Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing - I tried to figure out how to mark as code but it didn`t display properly, except for html code

Comment: You might be having a trailing slash problem.  It depends on your settings.py if that is the case.

Comment: try `<a href={% url 'homepage:account' %} target="_blank"></a>`

Comment: I tried already and when I do this it gives me, even for home-page display, a 500 server error; when I replace in my views `def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'home_page/homepage.html')` homepage.html for account.html, as expected I see the account page; the href in my html page works too, since I tried it as link form and button form, but something in my views should tell django that there is another html page; or I should add a slash in my urls `url(r'^account/$', views.account, name='account'),` and see what it gets...

Answer (score 0):

I only want to thank all those who took time to check my question and tried to give a solution.

I think it was my mistake that I did not post the code I have in my main urls.py file, so here it is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('home_page.urls', namespace="homepage")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Apparently, the problem was in that first prefix of the first url in the list:

I changed

```
url(r'^$'
```

for

```
url(r''
```

and now it calls whatever links I provide in my html pages.

Thanks all again